# How can i create a custom shaped button using polygon in wpf using xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

[custom style button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qodl9.png)

I want to create a custom-styled button that will have two labels and a text block as described in the image. Please help as I am new to WPF.

Comment: Microsoft provided very detailed documentation about WPF. start reading it if you want  to develop wpf application. if not, then you can *hire* a developer who can do that. stackoverflow is not a free code-writing service

Comment: Normally you'd right click on the button in the xaml designer and choose edit template and Select edit a copy. Look for the setter for the control template and be creative afterwards

Comment: No need to stop asking questions on StackOverflow.  Just try to keep in mind that it is intended for questions that are a bit more specific, whose answers could help others in the future and whose solutions aren't generally covered in publicly available tutorials.  We've all asked questions like yours at one time or another.  Regarding your question, let's just say this:  Odds are the approach you want involves writing a `ControlTemplate` for your button (i.e. setting its `Template` property).  In your reading, aim to learn about that

Comment: I have already done most of the design by setting its Template property but I am stuck while trying to change the shape of the button on the left Top/Bottom portion.

Comment: Actually, because you're new to WPF, what you want to achieve involves way too much : you must know how to edit a template, how to create a Path geometry (in xaml, use some vector tool like blend, it's pretty hard to nail the coords), how to clip a panel using a geometry, position some overlays, manage triggers and visual states (active, hover, disabled...) and the property updates, their nesting and interaction. It's pretty complex, there is no way a single answer could explain all that. You'll end up with a dozen of extra questions that are related but not specific.

Comment: The answer to your question is "use a path geometry as a border", but "how to make a border react as a button" or "how to update a button border according to mouse/keyboard action" are entirely different questions. If you can understand why those are very different concerns, please edit your question to address the specific matter (how to use a path geometry as a clipping border) while checking there is no duplicate here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions, Mean while I tried to learn path geometry and editing of system defined template and I have almost achieved it.